# jsf2 primefaces notification bar

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am wanna to have notification bar in my jsf page. When I use this sample code it works

```
    <p:notificationBar position="top" effect="slide" styleClass="top" widgetVar="notifBar">
        <h:outputText value="Hi ..." style="font-size:36px;" />
    </p:notificationBar>

    <p:commandButton value="Show2" onclick="PF('notifBar').show();" type="button"/>
```

but when I use this code it doesn't work

```
    <p:commandButton value="Show1" onclick="notifBar.show()" type="button"/>
```

Why and what does this PF do ?
My final approach is to have auto hide notification panel, but when I used code like this

```
    <p:commandButton value="Show2" onclick="PF('notifBar').show();setTimeout(PF('notifBar').hide, 3000)" type="button"/>
```

It shows this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'effect' of undefined
>   PrimeFaces.widget.NotificationBar.PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend.hide

and by this code

```
    <p:commandButton value="Show2" onclick="PF('notifBar').show();setTimeout(notifBar.hide, 3000)" type="button"/>
```

it shows

> Uncaught ReferenceError: notifBaris not defined

Could anyone help me please ..

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:commandButton value="Show1" onclick="notifBar.show()" type="button"/>
```

`notifBar` is equal to `widgetVar="notifBar"` which means its a client side component and your server doesn't know about `notifbar`, to show it, you have to do it like: `PF('client_Wiget_War').show;`

By Doc: 'widgetVar is the name of the client side variable'
[here](http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/)

WRT hiding notification bar

> Uncaught ReferenceError: notifBar is not defined

This occurrs because `notifBar` is client side component
For now I am trying to replicate your `setTimeout` scenario but i am failed.